# I need correct regex for time markers in video

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a regular expression to find time markers in the video from a string.
For example, I have this:

```
00:00 - вступление Сергея Немчинского
01:26 - профессия это не на всю жизнь
04:45 - важность выбора языка программирования
07:48 - системы управления контролем версий
09:51 - поисковик
12:10 - больше практики
13:12 - и больше отдыха
14:38 - программирование это больше чем синтаксис
17:15 - невозможно выучить все
10:19:38 - разберитесь в себе и делайте то, что нравится :)
```

I need to extract `[00:00, 01:26, 04:45, etc.]`
I have this `(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$` But it doesen't works properly.

Comment: The "end of string" anchor (`$`) doesn't seem to belong there.

Answer (score 2):

```py
s = '''00:00 - вступление Сергея Немчинского
01:26 - профессия это не на всю жизнь
04:45 - важность выбора языка программирования
07:48 - системы управления контролем версий
09:51 - поисковик
12:10 - больше практики
13:12 - и больше отдыха
14:38 - программирование это больше чем синтаксис
17:15 - невозможно выучить все
10:19:38 - разберитесь в себе и делайте то, что нравится :)'''

import re

re.findall(r'^\d[\d:]+', s, re.MULTILINE)

# ['00:00',
#  '01:26',
#  '04:45',
#  '07:48',
#  '09:51',
#  '12:10',
#  '13:12',
#  '14:38',
#  '17:15',
#  '10:19:38']
```

Description of the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/RcIodc/1)

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem otherwise it will keep coming up in the open question list :)

Comment: Yep, this will work! Just be sure there are no whitespaces at the start of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern contains optional capture groups for the first 2 parts. That way it will also match for example just `10`

You can omit the anhor `$` at the end, and add an anchor `^` at the start.

Then only make the last group optional as the last value in the example data `10:19:38` consists of 3 parts.

```
^(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d(?::[0-5]?\d)?\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])` Match from 00 to 19 or 20 to 23
- `:[0-5]?\d` Match from 00 to 59
- `(?::[0-5]?\d)?` Optionally match from 00 to 59
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zeCk1x/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NeFCLc)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"^(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d(?::[0-5]?\d)?\b"

s = ("00:00 - вступление Сергея Немчинского\n"
    "01:26 - профессия это не на всю жизнь\n"
    "04:45 - важность выбора языка программирования\n"
    "07:48 - системы управления контролем версий\n"
    "09:51 - поисковик\n"
    "12:10 - больше практики\n"
    "13:12 - и больше отдыха\n"
    "14:38 - программирование это больше чем синтаксис\n"
    "17:15 - невозможно выучить все\n"
    "10:19:38 - разберитесь в себе и делайте то, что нравится :)\n")
    
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['00:00', '01:26', '04:45', '07:48', '09:51', '12:10', '13:12', '14:38', '17:15', '10:19:38']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

- Time is always at the very start of a line
- Time can have format `00:00`, `00:00:00`, or `00:00:00.00`

Then:

```py
s = '''
00:00 - вступление Сергея Немчинского
01:26 - профессия это не на всю жизнь
04:45 - важность выбора языка программирования
07:48 - системы управления контролем версий
09:51 - поисковик
12:10 - больше практики
13:12 - и больше отдыха
14:38 - программирование это больше чем синтаксис
17:15 - невозможно выучить все
10:19:38 - разберитесь в себе и делайте то, что нравится :)
'''

# extract times as tuples of strings [('', '00', '00'), ('', '01, '26'), ...]
times = re.findall(r'^(?:(\d\d):)?(\d\d):(\d\d(?:\.\d*)?)', s, re.M)

# convert to integers and floats [(0, 0, 0.0), (0, 1, 26.0), ...]
times = [(int(h or 0), int(m), float(s or 0)) for h, m, s in times]

# convert to timedeltas [timedelta(0), timedelta(0, 86), ...]
times = [datetime.timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s) for h, m, s in times]

# results
for time in times:
    print(time)

0:00:00
0:01:26
0:04:45
0:07:48
0:09:51
0:12:10
0:13:12
0:14:38
0:17:15
10:19:38
```

The regex has these parts:

- `^` must start at beginning of line
- `(?:(\d\d):)` optional hour part like `00:`
- `(\d\d):` required minute part like `00:`
- `(\d\d(?:\.\d*)?)` required second part with optional decimal like `00` or `00.00`

Each number is grouped with `()` so that `findall` will return one string-number-per-element tuples.

The pattern `int(h or 0)` is used because the regex can return `''` which isn't a valid `int`, but `'' or 0` becomes `0` which is a valid `int`.